# ¿Cómo mostrar botones en un QLabel de PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

tengo el siguiente código en el que pretendo mostrar una imagen junto a dos botones en un QLabel:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel


class Guardar(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        QLabel.__init__(self)
        self.bol = False
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(sys.argv[1])
        self.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.button_box = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.button_box.accepted.connect(self.t)
        self.button_box.rejected.connect(self.f)
        self.addWidget(button_box)
        self.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    def f(self):
        self.bol = False
    def t(self):
        self.bol = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Guardar()
```

pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
  File "window.py", line 28, in <module>
    window = Guardar()
  File "window.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.addWidget(button_box)
AttributeError: 'Guardar' object has no attribute 'addWidget'
```

La pregunta sería cómo mostrar estos botones sin error, y mostrando la imagen, claro esta. Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: reformulo la pregunta

Comment: La causa del error es obvio: la clase QLabel no tiene un método llamado addWIdget pero el objetivo de fondo es confuso, podrias mostrar una imagen de lo que deseas obtener.

Comment: algo como lo siguiente pero en vez del matplotlib la imagen: (igualmente lo resolví creando dos ventanas pero para que quede registrado prosigamos) https://sofes.miximages.com/figure/E9gJa.png